# UV texture not rendered as seen by camera?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I have been working on a finger model and trying to add texture on that. I was successful, but the texture is not getting rendered as seen by the camera. In other way the orientation is different. The images are shown below:

The 3D model of the finger:
[image]

Next the texture i am trying to map on it.
[image]

The unwrapped layout along with texture:
[image]

This is model seen by the camera:
[image]

The final rendered image:
[image]

The nodes Editor layout:
[image]

As you can see, the rendered image and the texture seen by the camera is different.

Comment: Can you upload the blend file?

Comment: Even though UV is the default texture coordinate mode, I might try adding a texture coordinate node and connect the UV output to the vector input of the Image Texture and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh - The link for the files is : [link] https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3IeQ-na-m9rfnNrVGNtMXlsbmJRYXdld2JlTHg3Um9ZLVY2RURHd1ZBM0t2YmRNS3VtY2c&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 UV maps defined for the mesh, and the one selected ("UVMap") is applying the image texture the wrong way.

[image]

If you select the other map ("UVMap.001"), you'll get the mapping that you want.

[image]